# java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate dummy secret at sun.security.ssl.RSAClientKeyExchange.<init>

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ssl, glassfish

I am working on a Java EE application (Netbeans IDE 8.0.2, Glassfish 4.1, JDK 1.8.0_45).

The access to the pages of the application should be secured by https, so I modified my `web.xml`:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <description/>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

When I deploy & start Glassfish via Netbeans I can access my application via

```
https://localhost:8181/MyApp/
```

When I bundle my application in a .war file and deploy it manually to a copy of the same glassfish installation files netbeans uses, I get an exception while trying to connect to the application:

```
    WARNING (35) GRIZZLY0013: Exception during FilterChain execution
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate dummy secret
  at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1429)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:813)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
  at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
  at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLConnectionContext.unwrap(SSLConnectionContext.java:172)
  at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLUtils.handshakeUnwrap(SSLUtils.java:263)
  at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLBaseFilter.java:603)
  at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLBaseFilter.java:552)
  at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.handleRead(SSLBaseFilter.java:273)
  at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
  at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
  at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
  at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
  at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
  at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
  at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
  at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
  at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
  at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
  at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
  at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
  at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate dummy secret
  at sun.security.ssl.RSAClientKeyExchange.<init>(RSAClientKeyExchange.java:132)
  at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:238)
  at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
  at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:919)
  at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:916)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1369)
  at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLUtils.executeDelegatedTask(SSLUtils.java:247)
  at org.glassfish.grizzly.ssl.SSLBaseFilter.doHandshakeStep(SSLBaseFilter.java:638)
  ... 16 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:540)
  at sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.getCipher(JsseJce.java:229)
  at sun.security.ssl.RSAClientKeyExchange.<init>(RSAClientKeyExchange.java:115)
  ... 24 more
```

If I repeat the manual deployment process (.war) without the `CONFIDENTIAL` transport-guarantee in the web.xml I can access my application on

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/
```

What am I doing wrong? What does Netbeans right that I am doing wrong manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same problem, when I tried to switch my glassfish 4.1.1 domain to a custom JVM. I updated the `domain.xml` - which led to a similar Stacktrace.

I resolved the issue by resetting the `domain.xml` (no specific JVM or java home is specified in there anymore) and configured `AS_JAVA` in `glassfish\config\asenv.bat` like this:

```
SET AS_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\...
```